# When assigining an overloaded method in C# without specifying parameters, how to determine which one is used

Tags: c#, methods, overloading

I have a property

```
public Func<string, SomeDataTable> GetContactFromAlias { get; set; }
```

that I want to pass around/use from somewhere else and several overloaded functions

```
public SomeDataTable GetContact(string alias);
public SomeDataTable GetContact(string something, string other);
public SomeDataRow GetContact(Guid id);
```

. Does C# automatically determine the correct version of the function given the specified parameters? In my case, it works, but I wonder since typically, the left hand side of an assignment is (to my knowledge) not considered.

```
GetContactFromAlias = SomeClass.GetContact;
```

After all, with that notation, I cannot determine the function I want to use. I could of course do something like

```
GetContactFromAlias = (alias) => SomeClass.GetContact(alias);
```

but that is not as easy to read. Still, should I use the latter version, in case the compiler decides to treat the assignment differently at some point and it breaks? Or is there some smart mechanism at work that selects the correct overload?

Comment: It only becomes a problem if you change or add `SomeDataRow GetContact(string fubar);`

Comment: "Does C# automatically determine the correct version of the function given the specified parameters?" Of course. In this case, how can the overload that takes 2 strings be assigned to a delegate of type `Func<string, SomeDataTable>`? Their signatures are not compatible!

Comment: C# will lookup your parameters and decide which signature is valid.

Comment: I had enough assignments already that failed - though always at compile time (I had to be more specific), which it does not do here. Thanks for input!